# Prove $n\in \mathbb{N}^+,\sum_{k = 0}^n C(n, k) = 2^n$, using $\dots$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Question:**
55.) b.) Conclude that there are $C(m + n, n)$ paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(m , n)$.

57.) Prove $n\in \mathbb{N}^+,\sum_{k = 0}^n C(n, k) = 2^n$, using exercise 55.
[Hint: Count the number of paths with $n$ steps of the type described in exercise 55. Every such path must end at one of the points $(n-k, k)$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots n$].

[image]

**My Attempt:**
I've already proven exercise 55, but exercise 57 bothers me. I know for start using the fact that the path direction can be of the bit string $m + n$, that there would be $2^{m+n}$ path, but I'd like to use the Hint if possible. I have a hard time realizing the importance of the hint such as,

> Every such path must end at one of the points $(n-k, k)$ for $k = 0,
> > 1, 2, \dots n$.

I tried producing all the numbers of $(n-k, k)$ for $n=5+3=8$, and I get, $(7, 1), (6, 2), (5, 3), (4, 4), (3, 5), (2, 6), (1, 7), (0, 8)$, of course all of them end with $(5, 3)$.

Can someone elaborate that question for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each time you go either up or right. Either ... or ... is crucial here.

Comment: First path: ENNEEENE.  Second path: NEEEEENN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Calculate the number of ways to (0, n), (1, n - 1), (2, n - 2) ... (n, 0) and sum it in two ways

Comment: To others having problem, I limited my grid to 5x5.

Answer (score 0):

Each path of length $n$ is made up of R and U. R is for right, and U is for up. So think of it as a binary string of length $n$.

Suppose in a path of length $n$ there are $k$ R's, then it has to have $n-k$ U's to reach the destination. The number of such paths will be $C(n,k)$.

Thus the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n} C(n,k)$ represents all possible paths (binary strings) of length $n$. But the total number if such paths ( binary strings) can also be computed as $2^n$.

Hence the equality.